# css rainbow built using gradient colors and multiple divs

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

Related to this question 
[css rainbow built using gradient colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101349/css-rainbow-built-using-gradient-colors) 
is there any way to do this by using multiple `divs` instead of a single one? 
 
You might ask why when you can do this with only one, well for educational purposes. 
This is what I've done but it doesn't look that good. 
 Any ideas will be much appreciated.

```css
.mainDiv {
  display: inline-block;
}

.rainbow1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 55px;
  background: linear-gradient(78deg, red 5%, transparent 7%);
  float: left;
}

.rainbow2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 55px;
  background: linear-gradient(72deg, orange 12%, transparent 14%);
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="rainbow1"></div>
  <div class="rainbow2"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: If you found the solution with my answer kindly mark the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the `float:right` and used width to equalize the column. As per your ref example used the same gradient. I hope this will be helpful for you.

```css
.mainDiv {
  clear: both;
}
.rainbow1 {
    background: linear-gradient(78deg, red 5%, transparent 7%), linear-gradient(69deg, orange 10%, transparent 12%), linear-gradient(60deg, yellow 15%, transparent 17%), linear-gradient(51deg, green 20%, transparent 22%);
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
}
.rainbow2 {
    background: linear-gradient(43deg, blue 25%, transparent 27%), linear-gradient(35deg, indigo 30%, transparent 32%), linear-gradient(28deg, violet 35%, transparent 37%);
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="rainbow1"></div>
    <div class="rainbow2"></div>
</div>
```

Updated code for **three column** with `width:33%`. Attached the snippet for your reference.

```css
.mainDiv {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
}

.rainbow1 {
    background: linear-gradient(78deg, red 5%, transparent 7%), linear-gradient(69deg, orange 10%, transparent 12%), linear-gradient(60deg, yellow 15%, transparent 17%);
    height: 100px;
    width: 33%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.rainbow2 {
    background: linear-gradient(51deg, green 20%, transparent 22%), linear-gradient(43deg, blue 25%, transparent 27%);
    height: 100px;
    width: 33%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.rainbow3 {
    background: linear-gradient(35deg, indigo 30%, transparent 32%), linear-gradient(28deg, violet 35%, transparent 37%);
    height: 100px;
    width: 33%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="rainbow1"></div>
    <div class="rainbow2"></div>
    <div class="rainbow3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works fine but I have tried with 3 divs and each one with width 33% and it still doesn't show them all in one line. I don't know why it does not work, any ideas? Other than that it's fine.

Comment: @RazvanAxinie I have updated the code. kindly check.

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to consider multiple divs, I would get rid of the gradient and consider skew transform and solid background color to have the overlap.

Here is with 3 divs:

```css
.rainbow {
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
}
.rainbow > div {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   right:100%;
   transform-origin:top;
}
.rainbow > div:nth-last-child(1) {
  background:red;
  transform:skewX(8deg);
}
.rainbow > div:nth-last-child(2) {
  background:blue;
  transform:skewX(16deg);
}
.rainbow > div:nth-last-child(3) {
  background:yellow;
  transform:skewX(24deg);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="rainbow">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

You can easily scale to any number of divs.

```css
.rainbow {
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
}
.rainbow > div {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   right:100%;
   transform-origin:top;
}
.rainbow > div:nth-last-child(1) {
  background:red;
  transform:skewX(8deg);
}
.rainbow > div:nth-last-child(2) {
  background:blue;
  transform:skewX(16deg);
}
.rainbow > div:nth-last-child(3) {
  background:yellow;
  transform:skewX(24deg);
}
.rainbow > div:nth-last-child(4) {
  background:pink;
  transform:skewX(32deg);
}
.rainbow > div:nth-last-child(5) {
  background:purple;
  transform:skewX(40deg);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="rainbow">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

To have the fading you can consider a `blur` filter:

```css
.rainbow {
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.rainbow > div {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:-5px;
   width:100%;
   right:100%;
   transform-origin:top;
   filter:blur(2px);
}
.rainbow > div:nth-last-child(1) {
  background:red;
  transform:skewX(8deg);
}
.rainbow > div:nth-last-child(2) {
  background:blue;
  transform:skewX(16deg);
}
.rainbow > div:nth-last-child(3) {
  background:yellow;
  transform:skewX(24deg);
}
.rainbow > div:nth-last-child(4) {
  background:pink;
  transform:skewX(32deg);
}
.rainbow > div:nth-last-child(5) {
  background:purple;
  transform:skewX(40deg);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="rainbow">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks nice and it's definitely a good alternative. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with:

- multiple divs
- triangles made with borders
- shapes with different widths placed on top of each other, with their z-index adjusted accordingly

```css
div[class*="rainbow"] {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 position: absolute;
}

.rainbowRed {
 border-width: 200px 0 0 20px;
 border-color: transparent transparent transparent red;
 z-index: 7;
}

.rainbowOrange {
 border-width: 200px 0 0 40px;
 border-color: transparent transparent transparent orange;
 z-index: 6;
}

.rainbowYellow {
 border-width: 200px 0 0 70px;
 border-color: transparent transparent transparent yellow;
 z-index: 5;
}

.rainbowGreen {
 border-width: 200px 0 0 110px;
 border-color: transparent transparent transparent green; 
 z-index: 4;
}

.rainbowBlue {
 border-width: 200px 0 0 160px;
 border-color: transparent transparent transparent blue; 
 z-index: 3;
}

.rainbowIndigo {
 border-width: 200px 0 0 220px;
 border-color: transparent transparent transparent indigo;
 z-index: 2;
}

.rainbowViolet {
 border-width: 200px 0 0 290px;
 border-color: transparent transparent transparent violet;
 z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="rainbowRed"></div>
<div class="rainbowOrange"></div>
<div class="rainbowYellow"></div>
<div class="rainbowGreen"></div>
<div class="rainbowBlue"></div>
<div class="rainbowIndigo"></div>
<div class="rainbowViolet"></div>
```